# Why does my STM32 only run once when flashed?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, reset

I have a custom board with an embedded STM32L451RETx LQFP64. I can load a firmware using either a J-Link or a ST-Link probe and run it. My problem is that when I trigger a reset or shut down the power supply the MCU won't run boot.

I have verified the state of the BOOT0 pin which is tied to low. Tried also modifying the option bytes to override the physical pin (nSWBOOT0).

Power supply is ok, as well as decoupling capacitors (I have reused a PCB design and code that are functional).

The NRST is cabled acording to the MCU datasheet.
[image]

*Figure's reference: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l451cc.pdf*

Am I missing other parameters or configurations? I am thinking about the memory mapping, but I have never customized this part of a design.

Comment: Well, the problem is not in the parts of the schematics you show. It might be in the parts you don't show. Or in the PCB. Or in the power supply used to power the MCU. Or there is a manufacturing problem that is not visible except by looking at the PCB for manufacturing or soldering errors. Or then some component like a resitor or a capacitor is visibly OK but won't work due to damage.

Comment: Hector Silva-Diaz - You said that you can "*load a firmware using either a J-Link or a ST-Link probe and run it*" but when you "*trigger a reset or shut down the power supply the MCU won't run boot*". Did you detach the J-Link or ST-Link before doing your reset or power-cycle test, or was that still attached? I'm trying to clarify *exactly* what is different between the test which is successful and the one which fails. Are you sure you're programming the flash initially, not loading the code into RAM and running it there? Thanks.

Comment: At what address in flash does your code start? You should find this information in a .map file, or by looking at the output .hex or similar file which you load into your J-Link or similar flashing tool.

Comment: @Justme I have 3 boards that show the same issue. I had doubts about the power supply, so I tested with an external power supply but this wasn't successful. I will have to look deeper into decoupling circuits.

Comment: Are you using a debug build with some kind of semihosting to print some stuff to a debug console? That can be implemented with hard breakpoints (in flash) needing the debugger to continue when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: @brhans my code starts at 0x08010000, which according to the MCU's datasheet corresponds to the flash memory area. I found this in the STM32L451RETX_FLASH.ld file

Comment: @SamGibson to respond your second observation, I tried both configurations: with and without probe, none of them were functional. 
The succesful scenario is the following: the board is connected with a ST / J LINK probe, then powered up and programmed. After this, if the board is powered off and then on, there is no application running.

Comment: @Arsenal I tried both the debug and the release version of my application. How can I make sure that my release version is not built with semihosting?

Comment: @HectorSilva-Diaz The flash starts at 0x08000000. Unless you are doing something special and exotic then your code should start at that same address. There might be a reason why your linker script has a special address, but you need to know why.

Comment: @Justme Indeed. I thought that because 0x08010000 was within the flash memory space it would work. I just posted a response, thanks for confirming this.
I am still trying to understand why the linker file was set this way (I am not the owner of the code, so probably some old configuration).

Comment: @HectorSilva-Diaz it's of course a moot point now with the solution found, but semihosting is usually an option for the compiler, so you should check the compiler flags for the release build.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution after some long debugging sessions and reading.

For some reason the STM32L451RETX_FLASH and _RAM files had the FLASH memory origin set to 0x8010000. According to the datasheet (and after reading the comments) the flash memory **start** address is at 0x8000000.

[image: Source: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l451cc.pdf]

So I modified these files to match this, and then I set cubeprogrammer to flash at this address, and now the MCU boots after reset.

Comment: A typical use-case for a start address not corresponding to the start of the flash is a custom boot loader / boot part (whatever you want to call it) which often enables things like checking for a correct firmware and allowing a custom update protocol. That boot loader would then usually start your main application which starts at a known address. Reserving 64 kB for that seems a bit much, but depending on the protocols is still within reason.

Comment: Hector Silva-Diaz - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "[áccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to an answer to make it green - either [your answer](/help/self-answer) (which can be áccepted after 2023-09-06 @ 15.47 UTC i.e. 48 hrs after the question was asked) or another answer, if one is written (which can be accepted any time). That shows you don't need more help & future readers can quickly see the confirmed solution. Thanks.